# PyQt open another window

Tags: python, pyqt, window

I showed another window to the user when he clicks `'Go to work'` and hide current window. But when I hide current window, there's no application icon in the taskbar. How can I do what I want?
I want to show new window and hide current, but the icon in the taskbar is not showing.

```
def start(self):
        window = MainWindow(self)
        window.show()
        self.hide()
```

Comment: (1) Don't make the second window a child of the first. (2) Keep a reference to the second window using an attribute: `self.window = MainWindow(); self.window.show()`.

Answer (score 1):

Switch between self.hide() and self.showMinimized()

```
def start(self):
    window = MainWindow(self)
    window.show()
    self.showMinimized()
```